# Removing a package does not delete header and library files

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Previously, I had installed the OpenCV libraries on my machine, by running `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev`. Now, I want to completely remove these libraries and everything that was installed during this process.

To do this, I ran `sudo apt-get --purge remove libopencv-dev`. Then, if I ran `dpkg -s opencv-dev`, it printed out: `dpkg-query: package 'opencv-dev' is not installed and no information is available`. So, it appears that OpenCV was removed.

However, doing a search for any files including `opencv` in their name, I come across many, for example header files in `/usr/local/include` and library files in `/usr/local/lib`.

Why were these files not deleted when I removed the package?

Comment: With which search command?

Comment: Just using the search icon in Nautilus

Comment: packages installed with apt are not supposed to install headers in `/usr/local`. The files that you see there must have been installed by an installation from sources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An installation via package manager doesn't place files in `/usr/local`. I assume, you have placed the files in that location. Therefore the package manager can't remove them.

To be sure, check the output of

```
apt-file list libopencv-dev
```

---

`libopencv-dev` is a meta package. List all files which will be installed during the installation of `libopencv-dev`:

```
apt-cache depends libopencv-dev | awk '{system("apt-file list "$NF)}' | less
```

or only the packages

```
apt-cache depends libopencv-dev | awk '{print $NF}'
```

To remove the packages use (check the output with the previous command first)

```
apt-cache depends libopencv-dev | awk '{system("sudo apt-get remove "$NF)}'
```

Comment: Since the OP mentions header and library files specifically, it should be noted that `libopencv-dev` is a metapackage: all the actual header and library files are installed via its dependent sub-packages, and removing `libopencv-dev` on its own won't remove them (although a subsequent `autoremove` should).